# Add a Spinner while waiting for promise to resolve in react

Tags: reactjs, spinner, react-bootstrap

```
const fetchMusic= () => {
  return new Promise((resolve) =>
    setTimeout(() => {
      const music = musicList.sort(() => 0.5 - Math.random()).slice(0, 4);
      resolve({ data: music});
    }, 300)
  );
};

export default fetchMusic;


const getRandomMusic = () => {
  return fetchMusic().then((result) => result.data);
};

const Button = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Button {...props} onClick={getRandomMusic.bind(this)} />
      <SomeComponent /> 
      <p>Some text here</p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

I want add a spinner while waiting for the promise to resolve .
fetchMusic is in some other file.I m importing it in a component .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### TLDR

> How about use `useState` and `useCallback` for that action

### Answer

At terms of react, use `State` for loading action is right use case.
So, When to start function, use can `setLoading(true)` and after action you can `setLoading(false)` for make loading effect

```js
const fetchMusic= () => {
  return new Promise((resolve) =>
    setTimeout(() => {
      const music = musicList.sort(() => 0.5 - Math.random()).slice(0, 4);
      resolve({ data: music});
    }, 300)
  );
};

export default fetchMusic;

const Button = (props) => {
  const [loaidng, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const getRandomMusic = useCallback(() => {
      setLoading(true)
      return fetchMusic().then((result) => {
        setLoading(false);
        result.data
      });
  },[]);
  return (
    <div>
      <Button {...props} onClick={getRandomMusic.bind(this)} />
      {loading && <Sipinner/>}
      <SomeComponent /> 
      <p>Some text here</p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

### Reference

1. [Example of loading](https://www.basefactor.com/react-how-to-display-a-loading-indicator-on-fetch-calls)

### ETC

If you have any other question. Just give me comment please.